# Get constructor for Deserialization basis the Environment selected

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to deserialize a JSON file basis the environment selected by the user . My requirement is to select data fro JSON basis the Environment selected & convert them into Java Object for running my test script . Below is the research I could comup with so far .

**JSON file**  //Select the JSON array basis the environment(QA,STAGE)

```
{
"QA":{
  "customerName":"Customer QA",
  "customerAddr":"UK",
  "currency": "GBP"
 },
"STAGE" : {
   "customerName":"Customer STAGE",
   "customerAddr":"FRANCE",
   "currency": "EUR"
}
}
```

**Java Class**  //Class to transform JSON to Object . Call the constructor of the class basis the environment (QA,STAGE)

```
public class P {
 String customerName;
 String customerAddr;
 String currency;
 
P(String env,String customerName,String customerAddr,String currency)  
{
  if(env.equals("qa"){}
  if(env.equals("stage"){}

}
```

**Deserialization Class**    // Need to decide how to call the above class constructor basis the environment for deserializing

````
public static <T> T deserializeJson(String fileName, Class<T> T) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = JacksonUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(is, T);
    }```
````

Comment: You can't have two constructors with the same signature. Also, your JSON is not valid: You have an object inside `[]`, which is used for arrays.

Comment: Made the reqd changes , using single constructors ........Im  concerned with the approach to implement the remaining code (deserialization&how to pick json node basis the env) @JohannesKuhn

Comment: It is possible to add your configuration to the `DeserializationConfig`, could you add some json example and how it should be converted with different cases qa and stage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be multiple possible solutions for this. However, without knowing what you want to with it afterwards, its not really possible to tell which is best.

Personally I would make an additional class which holds the environments, as there should be a finite number of environments (currently we know about 2).

```
@Data
class Environment {
    @JsonProperty(value = "QA")
    UserData qa;
    @JsonProperty(value = "STAGE")
    UserData stage;
}
```

And `UserData` is your `P`:

```
@Data
class UserData {
    String customerName;
    String customerAddr;
    String currency;
}
```

Then you can parse it like this:

```
String json = "{\n" + "\"QA\":{\n" + "  \"customerName\":\"Customer QA\",\n"
        + "  \"customerAddr\":\"UK\",\n" + "  \"currency\": \"GBP\"\n" + " },\n"
        + "\"STAGE\" : {\n" + "   \"customerName\":\"Customer STAGE\",\n"
        + "   \"customerAddr\":\"FRANCE\",\n" + "   \"currency\": \"EUR\"\n" + "}\n"
        + "}";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Environment environment = objectMapper.readValue(json, Environment.class);
System.out.println(environment);
```

Which prints:

```
Environment(qa=UserData(customerName=Customer QA, customerAddr=UK, currency=GBP), stage=UserData(customerName=Customer STAGE, customerAddr=FRANCE, currency=EUR))
```

and lets you access the `UserData` by calling `environment.getQa();` or `environment.getStage();`.

---

Another possible solution utilizes the `TypeReference` that can be provided for `objectMapper.readValue()` method. Here we parse the JSON into a `Map<String, UserData>`, skipping the `Environment` class, which makes it more dynamic, allowing you to add new environments just through the JSON:

```
String json = "{\n" + "\"QA\":{\n" + "  \"customerName\":\"Customer QA\",\n"
        + "  \"customerAddr\":\"UK\",\n" + "  \"currency\": \"GBP\"\n" + " },\n"
        + "\"STAGE\" : {\n" + "   \"customerName\":\"Customer STAGE\",\n"
        + "   \"customerAddr\":\"FRANCE\",\n" + "   \"currency\": \"EUR\"\n" + "}\n"
        + "}";

TypeReference<Map<String, UserData>> type = new TypeReference<Map<String, UserData>>() {
};
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, UserData> readValue = objectMapper.readValue(json, type);
System.out.println(readValue.get("STAGE"));
```

This prints:

```
UserData(customerName=Customer STAGE, customerAddr=FRANCE, currency=EUR)
```